# How to open Guake immediately without transitions in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-unity

I am a user of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using Unity default inteface.

I use Guake, a Drop-down terminal for GNOME.

I want to open it immediately without transitions because of Unity.

What can i do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I find it! Open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo apt-get install ccsm
```

And then execute: `ccsm`.

Uncheck '*Animations*' to disable these kind of transitions.